# How can I limit the number of requests my Ktor Clientside can make to an endpoint?

Tags: kotlin, ktor, rate-limiting

I am using the Notion API and weirdly enough, I never receive the error code for exceeding the rate limit, my request just gets timed out, even with 3 retries spaced by 15 seconds each but I know I am exceeding the number of 3 request per seconds.

I found some thing in the documentation of ktor client side but I didn't understand how it works:

[image: Documentation]

I didn't understand what I tried, it made requests slower but not enough to be below 333ms.
I found some github things but it was made for Ktor server and I am using ktor client.

Comment: It will be very complicated to manage the rate using those parameters. For this, as you mention, you need a rate limiter. I'd recommend something with coroutines support, for example:
https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/getting-started-4

Answer (score 0):

when I faced the rate limit problem in my Shopify REST client app, I made a simply solution that delays the requests made to the backend:

```
class ShopifyRest(shopifyStore: ShopifyStore) : Rest() {

private val limit = 500
private var lastConnect = 0L

private fun throttle(@Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER") path: String? = null) {
    val diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastConnect
    if (diff < limit) {
        Thread.sleep(limit - diff)
    }
    lastConnect = System.currentTimeMillis()
}

fun delayedDelete(path: String): Response {
    throttle(path)
    return delete(path)
}

fun delayedPost(path: String, build: JsonObject): Response {
    throttle(path)
    return post(path, build)
}

fun delayedPut(path: String, build: JsonObject): Response {
    throttle(path)
    return put(path, build)
}
```

The *limit* val is the allowed rate time limit in milliseconds, Shopify imposes me with a rate limit of 0.5 seconds between requests.

The *throttle* fun could accept a *path* parameter for different routes or url's (in the code is not implemented) but I think that you can easily build a map of *path* -> *diff* values to keep different rate limits for different path's

I think that you have the idea how it works, but it works .

May be this feature will be implemented in the future in KTOR:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-6248/Rate-limiting-and-throttling-on-client-side